# Slick slider размывает изображение и оно похоже на low quality

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Сравнивая даже с заголовком "Brands" видно, что баннер размыт, если его открыть отдельно, все хорошо, качество очень большое. Возможно это происходит из-за масштабирования изображения самим слайдером. как быть?

Comment: К сожалению ничего не видно...

Answer (score 0):

Просто отключите useTransforms и useCSS в объекте конфигурации слайдера. Например:

```
$('.slider').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 4500,
  ladyload: 'ondemand',
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  useCSS: false,
  useTransform: false
});
```